# How to use LIKE operator with placeholder syntax in PostgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql

Suppose you have a query like this:

`SELECT * FROM the_table WHERE (name LIKE %$1%) LIMIT 10`

And a values array like this:

`[tyrone]`

The query works without the %% syntax used with LIKE operator. Is it possible to combine these ideas? Any reference to the LIKE operator I can find abandons the use of placeholders.

I am receiving the following error when attempting the query above:

> {"name":"error","length":90,"severity":"ERROR","code":"42601","position":"38","file":"scan.l","line":"1086","routine":"scanner_yyerror"}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SQL doesn't have string interpolation so you cannot use placeholders in string literals. You must instead use concatenation, e.g.

```
SELECT * FROM the_table WHERE (name LIKE '%' || $1 || '%') LIMIT 10
```

Note that the result of `'%' || NULL` is `NULL`.